How to float div when height change
I need to overide CSS in a wp plugin that show a grid of elements, so it's not possible to change structure or add classes.
So, lss, the structure is like this
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="box1 box"> Box1</div>
<div class="box"> Box2 </div>
<div class="box"> Box3 </div>
<div class="box"> Box4 </div>
<div class="box"> Box5 </div>
</div>

As you can see, only wrapper and 1st div have their own class.
So this is how plugin show grid:

Now, adding CSS, I had the desired layout:

.wrapper {display:inline}
.box {with:25%; float:left;}
.box1 {width:50%}

My goal is now to add a different height on hover on small boxes. Code is not a problem but, when height change, layout goes to hell.
This is what I'd like:

This is what I have:



.wrapper {width:100%;display:inline;}
.box {width:24%; height:100px;background:red;float:left;border:1px solid white;}
.box1 {width:49%; height:200px;background:green;float:left;}
.box:hover {height:300px;}
<div class="wrapper">
<div><div class="box1"> Box1</div></div>
<div><div class="box"> Box2 </div></div>
<div><div class="box"> Box3 </div></div>
<div><div class="box"> Box4 </div></div>
<div><div class="box"> Box5 </div></div>
</div>




sry, newbie as the kind of question shows :)
